# Is it possible to use XSS to read secured content

Tags: xss

I have read all about using tokens to prevent attackers from submitting malicious content to the site using XSS. My question is in regard to getting secured content from the site.

For example, we have an ecommerce site with the my account page where we list all the user previous orders, is it possible that an attacker can lure a user into a 3rd party site then init a script or something to pretend to be the user and grab the information from us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to LachlanB for putting in some additional info. After further research, it seems like I dont have to worry about this very specific case much because of the same origin policy most modern browsers apply.

"In computing, the same-origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number[1] – to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.[1] Same-origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequest and to robots.txt.[2]" Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. If someone can inject some javascript code onto your page by exploiting a XSS bug on your site, they could write some code to fetch all of the user's info. Or if someone snoops on your network (or the user's network) they could grab the user's session cookie.

If you're in .NET land, check out `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to help protect yourself, and use HTTPS for everything.

Comment: hi LachlanB, this is on the assumption that the attacker can somehow inject malicious code to my site right? How about the case when the attacker lures the user into a 3rd party site which is infested with malicious code which then from the user browser send requests to our site to retrieve data. Since the request to the user account page is normally a GET request, no csrf token is checked

Comment: Yes that's right. Well, normally the pages that serve up the user's data (eg account page) is protected behind a session, which is only served up to the user if they have a specific cookie. Read up on sessions and cookies first to get a background understanding to what's going on.

Comment: Yes I already have session to protect it but wondered about the use of XSS to read the content from an authorized person on a 3rd party site. Anyhow, it seems like due to same-origin policy this seems not possible, 1 less thing to worry about.